# Android - How to export database content to csv using PHP

Tags: php, android, http-post, okhttp

I have a MariaDB database where I insert data via a php file by making a post request.
I now want to retrieve all the database content via PHP in the form of CSV.

I've found a PHP file that downloads the database content as csv and it works.

This is the code I had at first:

```
String url = allConstants.BASE_URL + "exportData.php";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

The above code works but it opens up momentarily the browser and then the file is downloaded. I don't want that to happen. I want the file to be downloaded in the background without opening anything.

I have also tried using Async task and making a post request.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(allConstants.BASE_URL + "exportData.php")
            .method("GET", null)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .build();

    try
    {
         response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "reresponse: " + response);
    return null;
}
```

The above code seems to execute the PHP file, but no csv file is downloaded on device.

What modifications are needed for the above code in order to work?
Do I need to save the database content to a variable first and then save it to the user's device? If that's the case, I don't see why, since the PHP file does exactly that.